# DB2 Exception - There are no context policies

Tags: db2, ado.net

I am trying to connect to a Windows based DB2 server using the 11.5 ADO.NET connector. This works fine (it's some unit tests) on all systems except my home computer.

On my home computer I get the following exception:

```
{"ERROR [58005] [IBM][DB2.NET] SQL0902 An unexpected exception has occurred in  Process: 69336 Thread 11 AppDomain: Name:Tests: TestKailua
There are no context policies.
Function: AESEncryptADONET (Encryption Info)
allStack:    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool.HandleUnknownErrors(String strFncMsg, Exception exception, Boolean bThrow)\r\n   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool.EncryptString(String value)
at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool.ReplaceConnectionStringParms(DB2Connection connection, String szValue, DB2ConnSettings& pSettings, DB2ConnSettingsInternal& pSettingsInternal, Boolean bAttach, Boolean pushDownStrAppended)
at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
```

And the inner exception is:

```
AESEncryptADONET - Encryption - no error information available
at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool.EncryptString(String value)
```

What do I not have configured?

Comment: You have at least one working environment, and a failing environment. You need to determine the differences between the working and failing environments. Are the working environment(s) a member of the same domain that hosts the Db2-server, while your home computer is not?

Comment: Also verify you can connect to the same database (with same credentials) from your home computer *outside* of .net clr/ado.net. For example using the db2ntcmd.exe/db2cmd.exe command line (if your Db2 client includes that), or otherwise via the db2cli.exe command line, look in the Db2 online documentation for configuration details to allow these tools to work (i.e. configuring db2dsdriver.cfg for db2cli) and node-directory/db-directory for db2clp.

Comment: These error messages may be returned by many reasons so it is hard to point out the reason why.  Could it be possible to share the associated server side db2diag.log message(s)?

Comment: @hidehy Happy to share the log - how do I do that?

Comment: Could you edit your initial thread, adding the associated first or two message?

Comment: Do you use SSL to connect? Is it set up on your home computer? All clients would need to configure a key database etc.

Comment: @data_henrik I'm sorry, I don't understand your questions. I know SQL Server & MySql well, but DB2 (and Oracle) I know nothing. I just installed their JDBC driver and then run my test code. It is the same code hitting the same DB2 server on both systems.

Comment: @DavidThielen I would like to check PATH environment on OK and BAD machines.  Try to copy OK machine's PATH to BAD machine.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar problem. It worked on my local computer, but not on fresh new production server.

Problem fixed by installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable.